# What is a good/scalable way of calling command line tool in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a data processing binary which receive as input filenames, read data from one specified file and output to another file.

Suppose this binary executes in around 2 seconds.

What is a good way of using this data processing tool in a Rails App? I have some options:
 - Make the rails app write to a file, call the binary, wait for the output, read the output. 
 - Make something similar but instead of waiting for the binary to execute, just respond the request and asynchronously push data later.
 - Make some sort of web service just to run the data processing tool. Data is trasfered from the application server to another server through some HTTP request (possibly multipart).

Any other options/ideas?

Comment: Your best bet for scalability would probably be to have a 'web' server, which is main rails app, and have a 'job' or 'worker' server that will do the task asynchronously. Just because it executes in ~2 seconds, doesn't mean it always will. If your server gets overloaded, the tasks may get queued by the OS, and executed when it has the ability to.

Comment: This is really nebulous so we can only give opinions based on guesses, not specific answers based on facts. How many requests do you expect per minute now? How about a year from now? Will the input files get larger slowing processing time?

Comment: @the Tin Man: I don't think number of request per minute is so relevant for this question, that is why I didn't include in the first place. Mainly because I can scale horizontally by adding more application servers.

Comment: @JustinWood: cool, I was expecting something like that. This worker you suggest is something like a delayed_job?

Comment: Basically. @ChaseGilliam suggests using Sidekiq, which I have used in the past with great success. It basically does the work when it has the ability to.

Comment: @JustinWood do you have a good resource for using Sidekiq? I basically just tore apart the source with a coworker when we used it. I'd love to add a better resource to my answer.

Comment: @ChaseGilliam I do not. I usually just dig into documentation when I use a new technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) and S3. I would consider sending the files to [s3](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) then process them in a background job using Sidekiq to run the cli tool using `%x` if you want the direct output to STDOUT or `exec` if you want to return a bool for completion and redirect to results on `True`.

Just return 200 on the request if the file is uploaded to S3 and some statement about the job being processed. This is a sort of broad strokes version of how I would handle it.